# Apply CSS for first letter

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a HTML code where in the first letter has to be big and should be of 2 lines. Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="section-sect1">
  <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
  <div class="section-title">
    <span class="section-num"></span> Title</div>
  <div class="para">Text1
  </div>
  <div class="para">Text2
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.section-sect1 .para:first-of-type:first-letter {
 border: 1px solid;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}
```

Here is the fiddle link of the same. https://jsfiddle.net/8b5z8gb4/

Please let me know how Can I get this done.

Comment: .para:first-of-type:first-letter instead of this use this .para:first-letter for applying css for only first letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to select only the first letter of the first  `.para` use this

```css
.section-sect1 .section-title + .para:first-letter {
 border: 1px solid;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-sect1">
  <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
  <div class="section-title">
    <span class="section-num"></span> Title
  </div>
  <div class="para">Text1
  </div>
  <div class="para">Text2
  </div>
</div>
```

because the `.para` divs are not the only children inside the container , you can't use `:first-child` or something like that. so you need to use a sibling selector like `+` which selects the first `.para` after the `.section-title`

Answer (score 2):

Use `:first-letter` instead of `:first-of-type:first-letter`

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8b5z8gb4/1/) I have updated

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the below code.

---

```
.para::first-letter{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

With the use of `::first-letter` You can able to detect first letter in `para` class, Now you can style for first letter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks cool and don't focus much. Simply delete `:first-of-type` from your CSS and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

you can add first letter in class with style

like that:

```css
.firstcharacter { float: left; color: #903; font-size: 50px; line-height: 20px; padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 3px; font-family: Georgia; }
```

```html
<div class="section-sect1">
  <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
  <div class="section-title">
    <span class="section-num"></span> <span class='firstcharacter'>T</span>itle</div>
  <div class="para">Text1
  </div>
  <div class="para">Text2
  </div>
</div>
```

or you mast add test in tag p

like that:

```css
.string p:first-child:first-letter { float: left; color: #903; font-size: 50px; line-height: 20px; padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 3px; font-family: Georgia;}
.string p {margin-bottom: 0px;}
```

```html
<div class="section-sect1">
  <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
  <div class="section-title">
    <span class="section-num"></span> <span class='string'><p>Title</p></span></div>
  <div class="para">Text1
  </div>
  <div class="para">Text2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the first letter in a separate tag, then style that tag to look different:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold">F</span><p>irst paragraph</p>
```

Getting this:

**F**irst paragraph