# add css to named first children

Tags: html, css

This question can be the extension to my previous question [Apply CSS for first letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694577/apply-css-for-first-letter/38695379#38695379).

Now in my current scenario, I want to apply style for the first div with class as `section-sect1`'s para.

Below is my HTML.

```
<div class="chapter">
  <div class="figure">
    <img class="graphic" src="img.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-num"></span> Title</div>
    <div class="para">Text1
    </div>
    <div class="para">Text2
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-num"></span> Title</div>
    <div class="para">Text1
    </div>
    <div class="para">Text2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is

```
.chapter .section-sect1:first-of-type .section-title + .para:first-letter {
 border: 1px solid;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}
```

Here When I use the below CSS.

```
.chapter .section-sect1 .section-title + .para:first-letter {
 border: 1px solid;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}
```

it is selecting the first letter of all the `section-sect1`, But I want to select only the first `section-sect1` of `.chapter`.

Here is a working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8b5z8gb4/3/

please let me know how Can I fix this.

Comment: There is no `nth-of-class` selector.

Comment: If I understand you correctly here, you need this style applied to the first instance of `.para` in the first instance `.section-sect1`? If this is the case, you'll need to be particular with your `nth-child` selectors, because as @Paulie_D has already pointed out, there is no `nth-of-class` (hopefully we'll see this introduced into the spec in the near future, it would be very helpful). Here's an example of achieving this with `nth-child` selectors: `.chapter .section-sect1:nth-child(2) .section-title:first-of-type + .para:first-letter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, :first-of-type doesn't work with classes, only with html tags. However in your case, you could do something like this:

```
.chapter .figure + .section-sect1 .section-title + .para:first-letter {
    border: 1px solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

But if you can't use .figure, you will have to add a class on your first .section-sect1, or change his tag, so you can use a tag instead of a class in the css:

```
<div class="chapter">
  <div class="figure">
    <img class="graphic" src="img.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <section class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-num"></span> Title</div>
    <div class="para">Text1
    </div>
    <div class="para">Text2
    </div>
  </section>
    <section class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-num"></span> Title</div>
    <div class="para">Text1
    </div>
    <div class="para">Text2
    </div>
  </section>

</div>


.chapter section:first-of-type .section-title + .para:first-letter {
    border: 1px solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give child styling then you need to put data like tree.

I am attaching example for you, here is JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8b5z8gb4/6/

```
<div class="chapter">
  <div class="figure">
    <img class="graphic" src="img.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

  <!-- Child Holder -->
  <div class="child-holder">
  <!-- First Child -->
  <div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-num"></span> Title</div>
    <div class="para">Text1
    </div>
    <div class="para">Text2
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Second Child -->
  <div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-num"></span> Title 
     </div>
    <div class="para">Text1
    </div>
    <div class="para">Text2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

.chapter .child-holder .section-sect1:first-child {
 border: 1px solid;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is apply the class to all `.section-sect1` and then overwrite `.section-sect1` except the first using general sibling selector:

```css
.chapter .section-sect1 .section-title + .para:first-letter {
  border: 1px solid;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.chapter .section-sect1 ~ .section-sect1 .section-title  + .para:first-letter {
  border:none;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter">
  <div class="figure"><img class="graphic" src="img.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-num"></span> Title</div>
    <div class="para">Text1
    </div>
    <div class="para">Text2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_00001-SEC-1"></a>
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-num"></span> Title</div>
    <div class="para">Text1
    </div>
    <div class="para">Text2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```